# DataSet Value in Jquery C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one page in which, URL contains Querystring Value.

> QSecID=164&QTempId=55&QSecName=New%20Temp%20Bt

When the page loads them and tries to get the value it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      function getUrlParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
        var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
        var results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
      };
      var urlName = getUrlParameter('QSecName');
      alert(urlName);
      getImageData(urlName); //Pass Query String Value to Function
      });
```

Now I am passing this value to C#, ASPX.CS page and try to fetch the data based on `QSecName`.
But i got error. Here is my Jquery function.

```
function getImageData(name) {

  // alert(nextDay);
  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "Section.aspx/GetImageData",

    //data: '',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "dataSecName": name
    }),

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
      alert(JSON.parse(data.d));

    }

  });
}
```

My C# Page returns the DataSet in Jquery.

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetImageData(string dataSecName)
//public static string GetRole()
{
  clsSection objSectNew = new clsSection();
  DataSet DS = new DataSet();
  DS = objSectNew.GetImageDataByJQ(dataSecName);
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DS);
}
```

**Edit Code 1**
Here is my SQL Statement Which is get executed when i run the page and

```
DS = objSectNew.GetImageDataByJQ(dataSecName);
```

this method pass the query string value in to execute the Stored Procedure.

```
select mhp.ImageName,mhp.HotSpotID,imgdetail.XCordinate,imgdetail.YCordinate
        from tbl_SOAPDetailsInfo e inner join  M_ImageHotSpot mhp on e.ImgHotSpotName=mhp.ImgHotSpotNameByUser 
        inner join M_ImageHotSpotDetail imgdetail on mhp.HotSpotID=imgdetail.HotspotIDFK where e.SOAP_D_Name='New Temp Bt'
```

I want to use my `XCordinate`, `YCordinate` and `ImageName` to display image using jquery. but Inside the alert BOX

```
**[object] [object]**
```

error display. How can i get and assign this value X AND Y value and display in DIV.
**Edit Code 2**

```
ImageName               XCordinate  YCordinate
$parent in angularjs.png    1146    590
$parent in angularjs.png    1216    588
$parent in angularjs.png    1188    626
$parent in angularjs.png    1162    582
$parent in angularjs.png    1193    586
```

The Database Value. JSON FORMAT DATA

```
{"d":"{\"Table\":[{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1146\",\"YCordinate\":\"590\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1216\",\"YCordinate\":\"588\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1188\",\"YCordinate\":\"626\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1162\",\"YCordinate\":\"582\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1193\",\"YCordinate\":\"586\"}]}"}
```

Comment: Share the error message if possible.

Comment: What is your actual question? Please share the error. Where is the error occurring? In the C# or javascript?

Comment: @JonP Sir i have edited the code "EDIT Code 1". In which i have specify the error at the time of alert. Please help.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron sir i have edited the code "EDIT Code 1". please have a look. And Help me.

Comment: @JParmar: `[object] [object]` - That's not an error.  That's you trying to display a complex object as a string.  Use your browser's debugging tools, specifically the Network tab, to observe the actual response from the server and see if it's what you expect.  In general you should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to display debugging information to yourself.  The browser console can display much more than just a string.

Comment: @David Ok sir. I will check. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per your question `[object] [object]` is not an error. It means you cannot fetch it in a correct manner.

Though I am not sure what kind of data you are sending from your back-end code in `data` But you could try following way,

```
     var data = "{\"Table\":[{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1146\",\"YCordinate\":\"590\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1216\",\"YCordinate\":\"588\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1188\",\"YCordinate\":\"626\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1162\",\"YCordinate\":\"582\"},{\"ImageName\":\"$parent in angularjs.png\",\"ImagePath\":\"~/Administration/imageHotspot/$parent in angularjs.png\",\"HotSpotID\":11,\"XCordinate\":\"1193\",\"YCordinate\":\"586\"}]}"

            var obj = JSON.parse(data);

            console.log(obj.Table);
            var tableObj = obj.Table

            console.log(obj.Table);

            var arrayLength = tableObj.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                console.log(tableObj[i].ImageName);
                console.log(tableObj[i].XCordinate);
                console.log(tableObj[i].YCordinate);
                alert(tableObj[i].YCordinate);
               }
```

So now if you replace your code with above sample your code should look like below:

```
 function getImageData(name) {
            // alert(nextDay);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Section.aspx/GetImageData",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "dataSecName": name
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(obj.Table);
        var tableObj = obj.Table

        console.log(obj.Table);

        var arrayLength = tableObj.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            console.log(tableObj[i].ImageName);
            console.log(tableObj[i].XCordinate);
            console.log(tableObj[i].YCordinate);
            alert(tableObj[i].YCordinate);
                }

            });
        }
```

> **Note :** Try to debug in browser `console` you would understand object notation more details.

See the screen shot how would you do that

[image]

Hope this would help

Comment: Sir inside the console it shows me `undefined`. In My question i have edited code (Edit Code 2). please look.

Comment: What kind of data you are sending from back end code? give me a 2 sample data and class definition  too.

Comment: Additionally try `console.log(data);` it should look like this `{XCordinate: 99.5, YCordinate: 42.6, ImageName: "YourImageName"}`

Comment: Sir please see me Edit Code 2 Code, Here the json format is something different then what you have specified.

Comment: Hello see the updated answer. Hope it will work as expected. By the way you should handle your complex object on back end code if you are not competent on `JavaScript`